# Bayes interpretation of regularization in linear regression

Tags: statistics, summation, machine-learning, regularization

I am deriving L2 regularization by considering Bayes theorem. In doing so I came across the following article which stated that the probability of a parameter theta has a probability distribution that is normal with mean 0. I would like to ask why such an assumption is made when a uniform distribution seems more natural?

[image]

Comment: What article? What is $\theta$?  Would a uniform distribution be proper?

Comment: Apologies the article in question is http://bjlkeng.github.io/posts/probabilistic-interpretation-of-regularization/#id5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can say that the uniform distribution seems more natural as a prior distribution since it may seem better to assume that all possible values of a parameter are equally probable. However, that also means that you don't actually have any "prior" information about the parameter you want to estimate because "not having any information about something" actually means "all outcomes are equally probable". Moreover, if you use a uniform prior, the term $\log P(\theta)$ becomes constant and thus doesn't have any effect in the optimization step so you will have to get rid of it. Therefore, in this case, the maximum a posteriori estimate becomes equal to the MLE! and nothing new is actually done.

We use a distribution other than the uniform as a prior when we have some information about the parameters or we simply want to "impose" some distribution on them. In the case of L2 regression, we want our parameters to be "small" so we choose a normal distribution centered at zero which makes the values that are close to zero the most probable (in a normal distribution the mean is the most probable value), and thus we obtain smaller values for the parameters after estimation.

Comment: Could I also ask why the intercept is not regularized also?

Comment: @cojoye Can you point out to me what exactly is the intercept that you are talking about?

Comment: the example in my question regularises $ \beta_{0}$ however in most other examples it is not regularised and I wanted to ask why this might be?

Comment: OK, sometimes when we are dealing with fitting data points with large values, if you regularize all your parameters including the bias term, then your predictions may be small and very far away from the true values which result in underfitting. In fact, the bias term is not the only term you may want to avoid regularizing, you can take away the first few terms and regularize the rest. That depends on the complexity of the problem. Also, you might want to look at another philosophy on regularization which is penalizing terms that introduce more complexity and more out-of-sample error.

Comment: Not regularizing the theta 0 despite the bayes derivation indicating you should seems to be a wrong. Could it be said that since theta zero is the intercept, it is easy to see if it is bad fit, hence it is a convention per the words of Prof Andrew Ng in the machine learning course?

Comment: No, it's not wrong, you don't have to estimate all the parameters using the same method. In fact, you could estimation one parameter using some method or by an initial guess and estimate the other parameters using another method accordingly like Bayesian estimation. About the intercept, it is not a convention but rather by testing the model with and without regularization on the intercept and also other parameters until the best model is achieved